# Will a change to verificationCodeDuration be updated retrospectively?

Tags: users, config, verification

I've amended the time people have to verify an account, using:

```
'verificationCodeDuration' => 'P7D',
```

But, I've done this retrospectively, after the verification emails have all gone out (quite a lot of them). Will this new verification time be applied to verification links that have already been sent out? Or will I need to get those emails sent again, as only new verification links will have this applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check [UsersService->isVerificationCodeValidForUser()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UsersService#isVerificationCodeValidForUser-detail), you [can see](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/UsersService.php#L155) that it's taking the current date/time and subtracting the [verificationCodeDuration](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#verificationCodeDuration) config setting value, then comparing that to the `verificationCodeIssuedDate` time that is saved for that user in the `craft_users` table.  If the issued date/time is greater than the result of the subtraction date/time, then it's still valid, otherwise, not.

So because it's checking at runtime against the current date/time, the new `verificationCodeDuration` value will immediately take affect for any existing verification codes on a user.